# HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() fails for empty response header

Tags: c#, http

I am making a fairly basic call to a service using

```
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(PagePath);
{
    //Setting parameters
}
```

All seems fine. But, when I call

```
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

I get the dreaded

> "The server committed a protocol violation.
>   Section=ResponseStatusLine" exception.

But in this case the cause is clear, the solution is not!

> The server doesn't return any response headers, not even HTTP/1.0 200
>   OK.

This appears to cause the dot net framework code to fail with a Null reference exception which then translates to the "protocol violation" error.

Is it possible to bypass the header checking at all. Unfortunately  does not prevent this error if there are no headers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. Fundamentally the error is correct - the server committed a protocol violation. It didn't return a correct HTTP response. If you're trying to talk to a server that isn't going to speak valid HTTP, don't use an HTTP client.

Comment: I was afraid of that :-/

Comment: I delete my answer, because you tried already this. I advise you to contact the service provider and to fix his service.